# How do I get href values of a specific Link Text into a list so I can change them into a full URL?

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I want to scrape the href value of all links on a webpage By.LinkText("Click Here") into a list so I can change the beginning of the hrefs to something like "www.mysite.com/" to be able to access the sites at a later time.

The links are not in a single div but instead, are spread throughout the webpage which confuses me if xpath is usable in this case so I would like to use link text

Comment: Just get all the elements by their `tagName`, then iterate the collection and get the links text and process it as you see fit.

Comment: You can use `link.GetAttribute('href')`. Make sure to iterate through all the links .

Answer (score 1):

```
    List<String> link_list = new ArrayList<>();

   List<WebElement> link_elements = driver.findElements(By.LinkText("Click Here"));

   if (!link_elements.isEmpty())
   {
        for (WebElement e : link_elements) {
            String thishref = e.getAttribute("href");
            if (thishref==null){thishref = "";}

            if (link_list.contains(thishref)||"".equals(thishref))
            {

            }
            else
            {
                link_list.add(thishref);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I am not sure with this `thishref = e.getAttribute("src");`. @pcalkins can you share the sample page where you find a link with `src`, if any.

Comment: sorry, forgot to remove that.  That's for images.  (I was using some code that was multi-purpose.)  This was designed to collect src's when hrefs didn't exist.  I've updated it.